# WordPress > Gutenberg > How to add Popover to custom format type?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I want to extend the WordPress (Gutenberg) default block
**Paragraph** to give editors the possibility to add tooltips without writing code.

Goal:

- Add block **paragraph** and add some text
- Make a **text selection** and click on a (new) button (should appear next to text styles)
- Tooltip button should work exactly like the **link** button, only that it should be possible to **enter text** instead of a link

Working:

- I added a button (Text-Style)
- I can select text and I can add a class (.kf-tooltip)
- I know how to add a Tooltip via JS

Missing:

- How to add the Popover to enter the text for the tooltip
- How to store / save this data
- How to output this data as attribute (for example: data-tooltip="Lorem ipsum")

Any help would be awesome!

---

**WordPress Plugin**

```html
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: KF Custom
*/

add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', function () {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'kf-custom-script',
        plugins_url( 'kf-custom-script.js', __FILE__ ),
        array('wp-blocks', 'wp-rich-text')
    );
});

add_action( 'enqueue_block_assets', function () {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'kf-custom-style', plugins_url( 'style.css', __FILE__ ) );
});
```

**kf-custom-script.js**

```js
(function(wp){

    console.log(wp);

    // Create Popover
    const { Popover } = wp.components;

    var MyCustomButton = function( props ) {
        return wp.element.createElement(
            wp.blockEditor.RichTextToolbarButton, {
                icon: 'editor-code',
                title: 'Tooltip',
                onClick: function() {
                    console.log('Open Popup on this event');
                    props.onChange( wp.richText.toggleFormat(
                        props.value,
                        { type: 'my-custom-format/kf-tooltip' }
                    ) );
                },
                isActive: props.isActive,
            }
        );
    }

    var clickHandler = function( props ) {
        console.log('Open Popup on this event');
        return 'test';
    } 

    wp.richText.registerFormatType(
        'my-custom-format/kf-tooltip', {
            title: 'Tooltip',
            tagName: 'span',
            className: 'kf-tooltip',
            edit: MyCustomButton,
            click: clickHandler
        }
    );

})(window.wp)
```